# How to overlay circles with a bar chart on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, visualization

I am making a graph in python, and want to be able to have a circle where the median of each bar graph data point is. Right now the median of one group is under the variable medf

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
#import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

N = 4
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.25
cells = ['control', '15 cm', '30 cm', '30 cm homogenous']
medf = [ 17.89, 16.88,21.46,12.39]  #fdle median
xvals = [15.168, 18.201, 19.730,13.07] #fdle
errorf = [2.98, 2.71,1.79, 0.789 ] #fdle error
bar1 = plt.bar(ind, xvals,width,yerr=errorf, ecolor='grey', color='lightcoral')


yvals = [20.94 , 21.90,22.87, 20.20] #calu
errorc = [0.617 , 3.432,1.578, 2.1] #need to redo errpr
bar2 = plt.bar(ind + width, yvals, width,yerr=errorc,ecolor='grey', color='lightseagreen')

zvals = [15.47,16.44, 37.7,13.63 ] #rle
errorr = [3.37 , 0.66,17.01, 6.04]
bar3 = plt.bar(ind + width * 2, zvals, width,yerr=errorr,ecolor='grey', color='thistle')

grey_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='Standard Error')
#fig = px.box(df, x="cells", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
plt.xlabel("Pressure")
plt.ylabel('Distance (um)')
plt.title("Mean Total Distance Traveled")

plt.xticks(ind + width, ['Control', '15 cm', '30 cm', '30 cm homogenous'])
plt.legend((bar1, bar2, bar3,grey_patch), ('FDLE', 'CALU-3', 'RLE-6TN','Standard Error'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have tried using the following, but it has not worked for me

```
ax.scatter(df['Val2'].tolist(), [0,1,2], color=[1,0.8,0], zorder=2, label='Val2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this before you show the plot worked for me:

```
for i,e in enumerate(medf):
    plt.plot(i+0.25,e, marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="red", markerfacecolor="green")
```

The whole code now looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
#import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

N = 4
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.25
cells = ['control', '15 cm', '30 cm', '30 cm homogenous']
medf = [ 17.89, 16.88,21.46,12.39]  #fdle median
xvals = [15.168, 18.201, 19.730,13.07] #fdle
errorf = [2.98, 2.71,1.79, 0.789 ] #fdle error
bar1 = plt.bar(ind, xvals,width,yerr=errorf, ecolor='grey', color='lightcoral')

yvals = [20.94 , 21.90,22.87, 20.20] #calu
errorc = [0.617 , 3.432,1.578, 2.1] #need to redo errpr
bar2 = plt.bar(ind + width, yvals, width,yerr=errorc,ecolor='grey', color='lightseagreen')

zvals = [15.47,16.44, 37.7,13.63 ] #rle
errorr = [3.37 , 0.66,17.01, 6.04]
bar3 = plt.bar(ind + width * 2, zvals, width,yerr=errorr,ecolor='grey', color='thistle')

grey_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label='Standard Error')
#fig = px.box(df, x="cells", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
plt.xlabel("Pressure")
plt.ylabel('Distance (um)')
plt.title("Mean Total Distance Traveled")

plt.xticks(ind + width, ['Control', '15 cm', '30 cm', '30 cm homogenous'])
plt.legend((bar1, bar2, bar3,grey_patch), ('FDLE', 'CALU-3', 'RLE-6TN','Standard Error'))

for i,e in enumerate(medf):
    plt.plot(i+0.25,e, marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="red", markerfacecolor="green")

plt.show()
```

Hope this is helpfull